# Pastespecial in VBA code returns syntax error (Solution Provided in Title's Post Isn't Working)

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting caught up on a couple of (what I think would be) simple macros. Literally just trying to copy PasteValues a range of cells into another sheet while using Offset to drop the inputs into last row available on the other sheet.

Big picture, I am trying to create an "input" tab in Excel that will then take my various health & fitness values and plug them into other tabs in the workbook to be able to track over time. Below is a screenshot of "Input" tab I was talking about.[1]

The VBA that somewhat works is below:

```
Sub DataWarehouseCL()

Sheets("Input").Range("B11").Copy Sheets("Cardio Logs").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Sheets("Input").Range("B2").Copy Sheets("Cardio Logs").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Sheets("Input").Range("C11:E11").Copy Sheets("Cardio Logs").Range("C1:E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Range("B11:E11").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Cardio Logs").Select
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-255
Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

But I think that is a little extra... and don't want to overdo it and wind up with issues down the road. The VBA below this is the one that I think should work but keeps given me a syntax error.

```
Sub DataWarehouseWL()

Sheets("Input").Range("B6").Copy Sheets("Workout Logs").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
Sheets("Input").Range("B2").Copy Sheets("Workout Logs").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
Sheets("Input").Range("C6:F6").Copy Sheets("Workout Logs").Range("C1:F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
Range("B6:F6").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

Not sure if how I described it is making any sense.

```
[Input Tab][2]
[One of the tabs that I'd like to populate using Input Tab][3]
```

Comment: .Copy Destination:= syntax is not a .PasteSpecial operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out how to mark your answer, @Jeeped, as allowing me to answer my initial question. I was able to use your ".Value" ending and just replicated it for each cell. I know, not optimal, but it'll work and what I am doing is really just trying to track my own health and fitness measurements, macros (carbs/proteins/fats), gains/losses, etc., so I can build a program unique to my body and optimize my performance. Thanks again for taking the time to read and respond to my initial question!

@Jeeped response:

Sub DataWarehouseWL()

```
WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  WorkSheets("Input").Range("B6").Value
WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  WorkSheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("C1:F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  WorkSheets("Input").Range("C6:F6")
Range("B6:F6").ClearContents   'what worksheet does this belong to...?
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B2").Select
```

End Sub

Solution after minor replications:

Sub DataWarehouseWL()

```
WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  WorkSheets("Input").Range("B6").Value
WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  WorkSheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
Worksheets("Workout Logs").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  Worksheets("Input").Range("C6").Value
Worksheets("Workout Logs").Range("D1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  Worksheets("Input").Range("D6").Value
Worksheets("Workout Logs").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
  Worksheets("Input").Range("E6").Value
Sheets("Input").Range("F1").Copy Sheets("Workout 
  Logs").Range("F6").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Range("B6:F6").ClearContents
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("B2").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Use direct value transfer to pass `xlValues` across.

```
Sub DataWarehouseWL()

    WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
      WorkSheets("Input").Range("B6").Value
    WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
      WorkSheets("Input").Range("B2").Value
    WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("C1:F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = _
      WorkSheets("Input").Range("C6:F6")
    Range("B6:F6").ClearContents   'what worksheet does this belong to...?
    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

The easiest way to copy, paste values and formats is to copy a union of discontiguous cells where an offball blank cell is added to the original range. Without seeing your data I cannot suggest anything but assuming that column Z is empty then,

```
Sub DataWarehouseWL()

    WorkSheets("Input").Range("B6, Z6").Copy Destination:=WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    WorkSheets("Input").Range("B2, Z2").Copy Destination:=WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    WorkSheets("Input").Range("C6:F6, Z6").Copy Destination:=WorkSheets("Workout Logs").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    Range("B6:F6").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Whoa... y'alls follow-up was crazy fast, thanks! I Won't be able to confirm until tomorrow, but thanks for taking the time to provide an answer!